# Creating a .zip archive with Python in MS DOS

Tags: python, zip

I am new to programming. I am trying to learn Python using CH Swaroop's "Byte of Python". One example is to create a program which will backup some files from one directory to another and compress them into a .zip format. Unfortunately the example he gives is only helpful if you happen to be a linux/unix user. For windows users he says only "Windows users can use the Info-Zip program" but doesn't elaborate further. This is the code he provides ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename : backup_ver1.py

import os
import time


# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are specified in a list.
source = [r'C:\Users\ClickityCluck\Documents']

# 2. The backup must be stored in a main backup directory
target_dir = r'C:\Backup'
# 3. Zip seems good

# 4. Let's make the name of the file the current date/time
target = target_dir + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. We use the zip command to put the files in a zip archive
zip_command = "zip -qr '%s' %s" % (target, ''.join(source))

# Run Backup
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print "Succesful backup to", target
else:
    print 'BACKUP FAILED :('
```

Can anyone lay out for me a way to do this in the command line on windows 7? Thank you for your time and I apologize in advance if I have failed to provide some pertinent information :)

Comment: What a silly exercise. Python has `zipfile` and he's resorted to calling an external program? And on top of that it's teaching `os.system()` which is all but obsolete. Waste of time.

Comment: But if you care regardless... http://www.info-zip.org/

Comment: Python has had the `zipfile` module for *years*, since 2000. 'Byte of Python' is much newer than that.  http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Comment: if you want to do something on the command line you need to lookup the documentation for the zip program you are using. It will should explain how to do it. If you are really want to zip files, you should be using the python zip module.

Comment: MS DOS? You mean Windows, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3 users and using the format method answer should be:

```
   # 1. The files and directories to be backed up are specified in a list.
   source = [r'C\Users\MySourceDir']

   # 2. The backup must be stored in a # main backup directory
   target_dir = r'C:\Users\MyTargetDir'

   # 3. The files are backed up into a zip file.
   # 4. The name of the zip archive is the current date and time
   target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.7z'

   # Create target directory if it is not present
   if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
       os.mkdir(target_dir)

   # 5. We use the zip command to put the files in a zip archive
   zip_command = 'C:\\"Program Files"\\7-Zip\\7z a -t7z -r "{0}" "{1}"'.format(target,' '.join(source)) # be careful with spaces on each dir specification. Problems could arise if double-quotation marks aren't between them. 

   # Run the backup 
   print('Zip command is:') 
   print(zip_command)
   print('Running:')

   if os.system(zip_command) == 0: 
       print('Successful backup to', target)
   else: 
       print('Backup FAILED')
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is command line utility to create/update/extract ZIP archives, available on Unix/Linux/Mac OS X. If you want to archive files using a command line utility, you should find and install an appropriate on (`compress`, for example, is a part of resource kit).

The another way is to use python's `zipfile` module and make a useful command-line utility for windows :)

BTW, why your question refers to MS DOS?

Comment: Why should using `zipfile` be the other way of doing this? That should be the *first* way.

Comment: Not downvoting, but - he shouldn't have to invoke system commands for making a .zip file in Python, considering Python has module support for zip since 2000.

Comment: Some people think that Windows command prompt is the same as MS-DOS.

Comment: @birryree @sukhbir Maybe this is a part of the challenge?

Comment: `zip` is also available for Windows. But that's not the point. The point is that this exercise is doing more than one thing wrong.

Comment: khachik, well then you should specify that cause clearly, calling an external program using `os.system` (not even subprocess!) over a stdlib module is not a good challenge :)

Comment: @khachik, it's definitely not a challenge from [*Byte of Python*](http://www.swaroopch.com/files/byteofpython/byte_of_python_v192.pdf) (pages 78-79), because he writes code with system execution of `zip` as a solution to his problem. His reason for not using `zipfile` is ease of use and teaching, but I think it's more of a disservice to the end user to present an `os.system` way vs. the Python module way.

Comment: The 0th law of robotics by Isaac Asimov says: "the robot should do damage to human beings or let someone to do that" (sorry for my translation and my English). Daniel R. Olivo was the only robot who had been programmed to follow that law (everyone else followed the First /as the 0th, but for a human, not for human beings/, Second /the robot must follow the commands from a human if it doesn't violates the fist law/, Third /the robot should take care of itself, if it doesn't violates the first,second laws/ laws only, not the 0th)... (to be continued)

Comment: So D.R. Olivo stated that the best approach for it is "a minimum intervention". The OP seems to be very new to programming, so I did't think breaking everything down in his approach is the best thing I could do. If the OP is interested in the subject, after getting it working by `os.system` the OP will try to use `zipfile`. Maybe, I'm wrong, don't know :-/

Comment: @birryree Ok, see my comments above, downvote my answer, and post yours, I'm just tired, sorry. Thanks :)

Comment: @khachik - I'm not downvoting you, I was criticizing his book more for teaching in a way I think is not as effective as teaching it properly. I know @Zachariah is new, and it would be best to instill good practice in the language from the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# Filename: backup_ver1.py

import os
import time

# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are specified in a list.
source = ['C:\\Documents\\working_projects\\', 'C:\\Documents\\hot_tips\\']

# 2. The back up must be stored in a main back directory
target_dir = 'C:\\temp\\backup\\'

# 3. The files are backed up into a zip file

# 4. The name of the zip archive is the current date and time
target = target_dir + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.7z'

# 5.  We use the zip command to put the files in a zip archive
#zip_command = "zip -qr '%s' %s" % (target, ' '.join(source))
zip_command = 'C:\\"Program Files"\\7-Zip\\7z a -t7z "%s" %s' % (target, ' '.join(source))

# Run the backup
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful back up to', target
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'
```

Comment: Make sure use "\\" instead of "\" on windows: 'C:\\Documents\\hot_tips\\';  the above rendering removed all my double back slashes!

Comment: The point of the above code is less about showing off what Python can do on its own, but more about what it can leverage on the raw power of underlying OS and built-ins.